# simple random walk question

Tags: probability, random-walk

A simple random walk given as $S(n) = 0,1, 2, 3, ..., n$ representing the sum of i.i.d random variables, with the following:

$$P(Y_i = -1)=p, P(Y_i = 0)=1-p-q, P(Y_i=1)=q$$

Find $P[S(3)=0]$ when $p=0.15, q = 0.45$.

Given that we have a sum of i.i.d random variables, then $P(Y_3 = 0) = (1-p-q)^3=(1-0.15-0.45)^3=0.40^3$

First time working with random walks, I'm just basing this based on the i.i.d random variables. Have I correctly approached this?

We find that there are 9 combinations

$$\begin{align}(0,0,0) &= 0.40^3 \\ (0,1,0) &= 0.40^2\cdot0.15 \\(1,0,0) &= 0.40^2\cdot0.15 \\(1,1,0) &= 0.40\cdot0.15^2 \\(0,-1,0) &= 0.40^2\cdot0.45 \\(-1,0,0) &= 0.40^2\cdot0.45 \\(-1,-1,0) &= 0.40\cdot0.45^2 \\(1,-1,0) &= 0.40\cdot0.15\cdot0.45 \\(-1,1,0) &= 0.40\cdot0.15\cdot0.45 \\\end{align}$$

$$P[S(3)=0]=0.4^3+0.4^2\cdot \:0.15+0.4^2\cdot \:0.15+0.4\cdot \:0.15^2+0.4^2\cdot \:0.45+0.4^2\cdot \:0.45+0.4\cdot \:0.45^2+0.4\cdot \:0.15\cdot \:0.45+0.4\cdot \:0.15\cdot \:0.45 = 0.40$$

Comment: You considered the path that never moves, i.e. the increments $Y_i$ are $(0,0,0)$. What about the path with increments $(1,-1,0)$?

Comment: You should decompose your outcome in disjoint outcomes whose probabilities are easy to compute. Hint, in this case, if there is at least one move, then you know exactly what happened, except for the order of the moves.

Comment: @Ian I have to do the calculations for all possible paths when $0$ is the last destination?

Comment: Yes. There are only 27 paths total, and most of them don't bring you back to zero, so this is not as hard as it may sound at first.

Comment: @Ian thank you for confirming! As I understand it, the number of combinations with zero last is $\frac{2^3}{\binom{3}{1}} = 9$. Do I then take a final sum of of these probabilities? So $P[S(3) = 0] =\sum_i(x_i)^3$ where the $x_{i's}$ represent the combination of results?

Comment: You do sum up the probabilities of each of the paths that arrive back at zero, but there are not nine of those. This problem is small enough that I might suggest just going through and writing down all 27 paths and their probabilities to help your intuition, because you seem to have some problems with going via combinatorics.

Comment: @Ian So we can also have an increment such as $(-1,0)$? I say this because you mentioned they do not all have the same increments. On the note with combinatorics, I'm strongly convinced that 0 last is given only in 9 combinations.

Comment: You found $(0,0,0)$. I mentioned $(1,-1,0)$ in my first comment. Another is $(-1,1,0)$. There are a few more...

Comment: It's fewer than 9 combinations, actually.

Comment: @Ian I do apologise for the notation, I meant $3^3$ I was working on something similar with $n=2$, and so confused the notation. Thanks for you help, i'll update the question with the newer solution.

Comment: @Ian When I have $P[S(4)=0]$ what changes? For example, do I still have to find the combination out of 3, or out of four likeso (0,0,0,0)? So the larger n is, then I have to find an increasing number of combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comments into a partial answer:

First, it looks like you're making an important mistake: I think you're conflating $S(3)$, which is the position of the random walk after 3 steps, and $Y_3$, which is *the third step itself*.

In your amended question, you worked hard to compute $\mathbb P(Y_3 = 0)$. I can confirm that you have correctly computed the probability that the third step is $0$, because you have exhausted all possibilities for how that might occur. Note that $\mathbb P(Y_3 = 0)$ is *given* to be $1 - p - q = 1 - 0.15 - 0.45 = 0.40$. So, the good news is that your calculation is correct -- but the bad news is that it's not useful, because it's not what you were asked to find (and it's a consequence of things you already knew without the laborious computation).

Instead, you were asked to find the probability that the walk was at position $0$ after three steps. This happens in *three* of the paths that you evaluated above -- specifically, $(1, -1, 0)$, $(-1, 1, 0)$, and $(0, 0, 0)$. However, there are others that you didn't consider that are relevant, such as $(1, 0, -1)$. Your task is to find all the triples that sum to $0$.

This can be daunting at first, but it might be easier if you group similar cases together. For instance, you already found the probabilities of $(1, -1, 0)$ and $(-1, 1, 0)$ to be the same; note that this is *also* the same as the probability of $(1, 0, -1)$, as well as several other paths that are unstated so far. So, you might consider grouping them by type and then *counting* how many of them there are.

Regarding your latest question in the comments: yes, directly counting the cases (as you've started to do) becomes considerably more complicated when you proceed to 4 steps. However, if you consider the grouping approach I outlined, the *types* don't get too much worse than they already are.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, I believe that I understand the pattern. For example, we have the following: $(1, -1, 0),(-1, 1, 0),(0, 0, 0), (1, 0,-1),(-1, 0, 1), (0, 1, -1),(0, -1, 1)$ for the required paths to calculate, because they all sum to 0. Therefore, the calculation becomes $P[S(3)=0]=0.40^3+0.40\cdot0.15\cdot0.45 +0.40\cdot0.15\cdot0.45+0.40\cdot0.15\cdot0.45+0.40\cdot0.15\cdot0.45+0.40\cdot0.15\cdot0.45+0.40\cdot0.15\cdot0.45=0.226$

Comment: You've got it! Or, if you group by terms as I suggested, you can present this more compactly: $0.40^3 + \fbox{$\color{blue}{6}$} \cdot 0.40 \cdot 0.15 \cdot 0.45 = 0.226$.